# Error: We've tried to resolve your step definitions at src/integration/ but that doesn't seem to exist

Tags: cucumber, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I am trying to configure cucumber with cypress in my Angular project.
I have changed Cypress.json as followed :

```
{
    "fileServerFolder": ".",
    "fixturesFolder": "./src/fixtures",
    "integrationFolder": "./src/integration",
    "pluginsFile": "./src/plugins",
    "supportFile": "./src/support",
    "testFiles": "**/*.feature",
}
```

Then under integration folder, I have organized files and folders as shown in the screenshot bellow:

[image]

Then I have added this under my package.json file :

```
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "step_definitions": "./e2e/src/integration",
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true
  }
```

When I run cypress, then run the feature firstOne.feature, I get the following error:
[image]

Comment: Have you added the file:preprocessor to your plugins/index.js?

Comment: Also have you tried giving path from base directory say root/e2e/src/integration?

Comment: @niharika_neo yes I have added it :  on('file:preprocessor', cucumber())

Comment: @niharika_neo I have tried the base directory so I had a new error : Error: Can't walk dependency graph: Cannot find module 'root\e2e\src\support'

Comment: Can you show your full folder structure - root just meant your root, not the word root?

Answer (score 4):

Your `feature` files should not be in a separate folder. They should be where you specified in your `package.json` at `stepDefinitions`

Cypress-cucumber-preprocessor recommends this folder structure when you set `"nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true` and `"stepDefinitions": "./src/integration"` in `package.json`.

See doc [here](https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor#step-definitions).

```
- src/
  - integration/
    - firstOne.feature
    - firstOne/
      - firstOne.js
    - secondOne.feature
    - secondOne/
      - secondOne.js
```

So:

1. Create your `.feature` file in `./src/integration`
2. Create a folder with the same name as your `.feature` file, also in `cypress/integration`
3. Create a `.js` file in the newly created folder with your step definitions

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. I re-organized the folder as you mentionned. I got a new error : Error: Can't walk dependency graph: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\w\Desktop\cucumber2\um-front\e2e\src\support' from 'C:\Users\w\Desktop\cucumber2\um-front\e2e\src\_fake.js'

Comment: Do you have a file named `src_fake.js` in folder `e2e`?